# How do I read a tuple struct from a Wasm memory buffer?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, webassembly

I have defined a tuple struct:

```
pub struct ChangedCell(pub bool, pub u32, pub u32);
```

**My Assumption**

`ChangedCell` weighs 9 bytes (`bool`: 1 byte, `u32`: 4 bytes, `u32`: 4 bytes)

**What I Did**

I returned a `pointer, length` for `Vec<ChangedCell>` to JavaScript:

```js
const arr = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, pointer, length * 9);
```

```js
function getElements(n,arr) {

    const isVal = arr[n * 9 + 0];
    const val1 = arr.slice(n * 9 + 1, n * 9 + 5);
    const val2 = arr.slice(n * 9 + 5, n * 9 + 9);
    return {isVal,val1,val2}
}
```

**Expected behaviour**

- `isVal` to be `valid [byte]`
- `val1` to be `valid [byte] * 4`
- `val2` to be `valid [byte] * 4`

**Question**

`I am getting Garbage values!`
How do you read something like this into JavaScript?

Comment: To help people answer your question, you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not just snippets of the code and state what you expect and what result you currently get, not just "it's not working".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you are going to assume a particular layout you should mark your type as `repr(C)`:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct ChangedCell(pub bool, pub u32, pub u32);
```

It is likely that you get the same layout with our without the `repr(C)`, but you only get a guarantee if you write it explicitly.

Now you are guaranteed a C compatible layout, that (beware of the padding!) in wasm32 will be:

- bool: at offset **0**, 1 byte, 0x00 or 0x01.
- u32: at offset **4**, 4 bytes,
- u32: at offset **8**, 4 bytes,

Total size: 12 bytes. Bytes 1, 2 and 3 are padding and thus unused.